# How can I get my custom WPF usercontrol to bind to the content property?

Tags: wpf

I have the following as a custom user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestGUI.TBorder">
<Border Style="{StaticResource brdListBoxItem}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="35" />
            <RowDefinition Height="5" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Style="{StaticResource tblTitleDataStyle}"
                   Text="{Binding Header, Mode=OneWay}" />

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Margin="5,2"
                   Fill="{StaticResource BlueTextBrush}"
                   Height="1"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />

        <ContentPresenter Name="ccpMain"
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Content="{Binding Content}" />
        <!--<TextBlock Grid.Row="2"
                   Text="TEST HERE" />-->
    </Grid>

</Border>
```

If I comment out the "ContentPresenter", and uncomment the "TextBlock", it appears as expected.  If I have it as set, then only thing that displays is whatever is inside of the tags.  For example:

```
<local:TBorder Grid.Row="2"
                        Grid.Column="0" Width="300"
                        Header="The Header">
        <TextBlock Text="astnouhe" />
    </local:TBorder>
```

displays only the "TextBlock".

Can someone explain this to me?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What did you set the content to? If you are setting it to the XAML that you have in your question, then what it is doing is trying to display the text itself in your control.

You'll need to create another control that uses the XAML in your answer, and set that to the content of your user control in order to display those controls in side the user control.

Comment: I understand what you said in your first paragraph, but you lost me on the solution in the second.  Sorry for being dense.

Comment: @Salko73 It's ok. :) Basically, you can't just set some XAML to a property and have WPF render the controls - you'll need to set the actual controls to the content property in order for them to be rendered on screen. Does that help?

Comment: It does make sense.  For future reference, this link helped me translate it into actual code: http://10rem.net/blog/2010/02/05/creating-customized-usercontrols-deriving-from-contentcontrol-in-wpf-4  Thanks for your help.